# How to add extra into text into flutter google map custom marker?

Tags: google-maps, flutter, google-maps-markers

The problem is how to infuse text overlap on the custom google map marker with text which represents the vehicle registration number.

I have tried to use this method to have the text overlay on the icon
builder: (context) =>()
But is not recognized at all.

```
  class MapsDemo extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    State createState() => MapsDemoState();
  }

class MapsDemoState extends State<MapsDemo> {

  GoogleMapController mapController;
 //Map<PermissionGroup, PermissionStatus> permissions = await PermissionHandler().requestPermissions([PermissionGroup.contacts]);import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
          body: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
            Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: GoogleMap(
                 onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                   mapController = controller;
                 },
                ),
            ),
           ],
         ),
         floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () {
        
          double mq1 = MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio;
          String icon = "images/car.png";
          if (mq1>1.5 && mq1<2.5) {icon = "images/car2.png";}
          else if(mq1 >= 2.5){icon = "images/car3.png";}
          print("Mq 1"+mq1.toStringAsFixed(5));
          String iconPath="lib/assets/move@3x.png";
          
          
         mapController.addMarker(
              MarkerOptions(
                position: LatLng(37.4219999, -122.0862462),
                infoWindowText: InfoWindowText("TEST","TEST"),
                icon: BitmapDescriptor.fromAsset(iconPath),
                consumeTapEvents: true,
                
                /*builder: (context) =>(

                )*/

                //icon:BitmapDescriptor.fromAsset(assetName)
              ),
         );
         
         mapController.addMarker(
              MarkerOptions(
                position: LatLng(38.4219999, -122.0862462),
                infoWindowText: InfoWindowText("tt","adfaf"),
                icon: BitmapDescriptor.fromAsset("lib/assets/logo.png"),
                anchor: Offset(100,160),
              
                //icon:BitmapDescriptor.fromAsset(assetName)
              ),
         );
       
         mapController.animateCamera(
            CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
              CameraPosition(
                target: LatLng(37.4219999, -122.0862462),
               
                zoom: 15.0,
              ),
            ),
          );
       
        })
      );
    
  }
  
}
```

[image]

What I have shown is the icon appear correctly if you notice the white space on the right of the icon is where I want the registration number to appear.

Comment: Could you please edit the screenshot into the question? It's best if everything required to answer the question is included: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @MiloP I dont get you what to edit on the screenshot? Is it not visible?

Comment: @anmol.majhail any idea how to bring the text into the white space dynamically now for flutter I need to get that quite badly to move forward with the app. I even tried to have the window text open permanently neither that works either

Comment: @newbie have you checked this example? https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/google_maps_flutter/example/lib/place_marker.dart 
This example is using InfoWindowText normally.

Comment: @aubykhan yes I have even used in my example code above infoWindowText: InfoWindowText("TEST","TEST"), but the problem it only appear when I tapped on the icon. If possible I want all the icon's infowindow open automatically? Is that possible now ?

Comment: Any news on this? I also need something like a label to show some text with the marker.

Comment: @SEG.Veenstra I am also still awaiting any news on this I doubt any maybe others could help us

Comment: We could generate a new icon image with the label baked into it... Luckily I don't need it for now because I have no idea on how I would do that haha

Comment: @SEG.Veenstra but that is not dynamically right?  I am still looking for a dynamic solution still

Comment: It can be dynamic... but you will have to 'create' the images at runtime.

Comment: @SEG.Veenstra how to do that I dont get you do you have any code snippet?

Comment: I don't, it's just an idea.

Comment: When you remove the '()' from the onPressed what happens? You may need to replace the trailing { } with an actual method. It should automatically execute the method but I'm wondering if the text appears.

Comment: @F-1 I dont get you what you are referring too ?

Comment: @newbie sorry, I was referring to this comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54041830/how-to-add-extra-into-text-into-flutter-google-map-custom-marker?noredirect=1#comment95134723_54041830

Answer (score 6):

try this :

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

class MapsDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => MapsDemoState();
}

class MapsDemoState extends State<MapsDemo> {
  final Set<Marker> _markers = {};

  void _onAddMarkerButtonPressed() {
    print('in _onAddMarkerButtonPressed()');
    setState(() {
      _markers.add(Marker(
        // This marker id can be anything that uniquely identifies each marker.
        markerId: MarkerId("111"),
        position: LatLng(30.666, 76.8127),
        infoWindow: InfoWindow(
          title: "bingo! This works",
        ),
        icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
      ));
    });
    print('setState() done');
  }

  GoogleMapController mapController;
  //Map<PermissionGroup, PermissionStatus> permissions = await PermissionHandler().requestPermissions([PermissionGroup.contacts]);import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: GoogleMap(
                markers: _markers,
                onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                  mapController = controller;
                },
                initialCameraPosition:
                    CameraPosition(target: LatLng(30.666, 76.8127), zoom: 15),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () {
          print('in fab()');
          double mq1 = MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio;



          _onAddMarkerButtonPressed();

          mapController.animateCamera(
            CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
              CameraPosition(
                target: LatLng(30.666, 76.8127),
                zoom: 15.0,
              ),
            ),
          );
        }));
  }
}
```

Comment: Note : I've removed some part of your code and focused on showing the overlaid text on marker tap.

Comment: but that does not show the label as per my requirement in the picture above in my question right? can you see in my icon I have that white space is where I want the label to be displayed.

Comment: You are right. Check on 'overlay widgets'. That will serve the purpose. Meanwhile, I'll try post another version of the code some time today.

Comment: Unfortunately, marker doesn't support overlay. However, we can show an overlay on GoogleMaps. What you can probably do is to show the list of vehicle at the bottom (i.e. below Google Map) and we can show the text as you desired when user tap on the list view. Sample implementation (using TextFormField instead of ListTile) at https://pastebin.com/hQr5HBV2

Comment: I get your idea but the requirement is to have he text "overlay" permanently so at one glance user can see the vehicles and no need to tap or click.

Comment: I understand. In my code snippet at pastebin, all you have to do is to add following lines in before _onAddMarkerButtonPressed();
 this._overlayEntry = this._createOverlayEntry();
          Overlay.of(context).insert(this._overlayEntry);

So, as soon as user taps on Fab, marker is added and overlay text is shown.

Comment: Did you try the latest code ? It adds the custom overlay text to the point you specify.

Comment: I keep getting this errorMediaQuery.of() called with a context that does not contain a MediaQuery.
I/flutter (13480): No MediaQuery ancestor could be found starting from the context that was passed to MediaQuery.of(). When I have off this line double mq1 = MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio;

Comment: I think it’s a different issue. If the overlay stuff works as you desired then you might want to ‘accept’ the answer and continue to work on Mediaquery separately. In theory, you will need a class which is a conjunction of marker and he overlay text.

Comment: Hi sorry I tried the problem is that the mediaquery get coming I cant solve. On top that I went through the overlay codes. I notice its any overlay on a fix location. Secondly I will be having more than 1 marker so I dont think it can work with overlay?

Comment: The overlay location can be dynamic. Plus there can be multiple overlay widgets. My code is only for the demo purpose.

Comment: One more thing - the overlay widget is the option available with us. Google Maps for Flutter don’t support the custom text natively.  It might be a pain determining locations but that’s the only shot.

Comment: ok let me debug my issue with the media query to see the output cause I cant resolve that means I cant see the output and wont be able to confirm it that works. So how you suggest to determine the location on the map with the pin ?

Comment: yes I appreciate your effort and solution I agree for now other solution left yours is the only solution. But how to keep determining the screen size etc then only we can move forward rite.

Comment: Thanks. Determining screen-size is not difficult (as I thought earlier) or even determining exact position to show the overlay. We've lat-long of all the four corner, we've lat-long of marker, we've media query height and width. We just make use of it. Draw it on a paper and things will be clear to you.

Answer (score 2):

I kludged/solved this by creating a function which returned a , whose returned and resolved value   I then passed in as the icon when initializing a Marker:

Sorry to say that I don't remember why I padded the   method with the magic 40 and 20 constants. Probably calculated by visual test with what I was rendering at the time.

```
Future<BitmapDescriptor> createCustomMarkerBitmap(/* your args here */) async {

PictureRecorder recorder = new PictureRecorder();
Canvas c = new Canvas(recorder);

/* Do your painting of the custom icon here, including drawing text, shapes, etc. */

Picture p = recorder.endRecording();
ByteData pngBytes = await (await p.toImage(
    tp.width.toInt() + 40, tp.height.toInt() + 20))
    .toByteData(format: ImageByteFormat.png);

Uint8List data = Uint8List.view(pngBytes.buffer);

return BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(data);
}
```

Then when creating the marker, you can pass in the BitmapDescriptor as the icon, like so:

```
createCustomMarkerBitmap(...).then((BitmapDescriptor bitmapDescriptor) {
```

_markers.add(new Marker(
/*  in addition to your other properties: */
icon: bitmapDescriptor,
));
});

or:

```
BitmapDescriptor bitmapDescriptor = await createCustomMarkerBitmap(...);
```

Marker marker = Marker(
/*  in addition to your other properties: */
icon: bitmapDescriptor
);

Let me know if that helps. Gl!

I have found this answer for github issue

Comment: how to call this function with my existing icon? I don't quite get it

Comment: can you give the full code or getting image and draw text on it.?

Answer (score 0):

I found myself on this exact stackoverflow page multiple times this year. So, I decided to go and make my first Flutter Package and created this. If your objective is to add a simple and clear text to map marker, this would do it.

https://pub.dev/packages/label_marker

#### Usage

```dart
markers.addLabelMarker(LabelMarker(
    label: "TextToShow",
    markerId: MarkerId("idString"),
    position: LatLng(10.0, 11.0),
    backgroundColor: Colors.green,
    )).then((value) {
    setState(() {});
    },
);
```

Comment: I edited your answer to include the usage code of your package. It's a nice package, but it looks like it can only display labels and not icons. Maybe you can edit your answer and show how to display custom icons as well if my conclusion is not correct.