# Flutter show marker's infoWindowText by default in Google map widget

Tags: flutter, google-maps-markers

Can anyone suggest if there is a way of keeping infoWindowText showing when I open the Google map widget in Flutter (without having to click the marker first)? or a similar way of keeping a Text widget above a specific marker? Thanks in advance ~~

Comment: What is your main goal? Do you want to show information with your marker as asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54041830/1093801 ?

Comment: I have the same issue. I've looked at the link in the first comment and my requirement isn't quite the same. I just want to have the markers open when the map opens.